# (newbie post) PHP dropdown list, to insert a value from a dropdown list into database

Tags: php

could someone please help me with this problem, sorry for the Language in the code. Im trying to make it that way, that when someone selects a option and clicks the button that it will be inserted into my database, I already checked out if the name are all correct and such, and they are.

Note: Im not trying to select a value from my database, into my dropdown list, only to insert the value, like a application form for an account.

Note: If someone has asked the same question, it would be Awesome! if you could paste link in the comments, Thanks.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<select name="room" value="options">
<option value="Einstaklings" name="102">Alment Einstaklings Herbergi</option>
<option value="Tveggja" name="102">Alment Tveggja manna Herbergi</option>
<option value="Business" name="201">Business Herbergi</option>
<option value="Fjolskyldu" name="301">Fjölskyldu Herbergi</option>
<option value="Svitu" name="401">Svítu</option>
</SELECT>
<input type="submit" value="Senda"/>
</form>

<?php

$db_tengi=@mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    if (!$db_tengi) {
        exit('<p>Cant Connect</p>');
    };

if(!@mysql_select_db('hotel')){
    exit('<p>Cant Connect</p>');
};



$room = array(
'Einstaklings' => 101,
'Tveggja' =>102,
'Business' => 201,
'Fjolskyldu' =>301,
'Svítu' => 401
 );

function generateSelect($name = '', $options = array()) {
$html = '<select name="'.$name.'">';
foreach ($options as $option => $value) {
    $html .= '<option value='.$value.'>'.$option.'</option>';
}
$html .= '</select>';
return $html;
 }
 $html = generateSelect('room', $room);


 if (
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `registration` SET 
    room_ID_FK='$room'"
    )
    if(@mysql_query($sql)){
        echo '<p> Insert Complete</p>';
    }
    else{
        echo '<p> Error Insert failed.' . mysql_error() . '</p>'; 
    };


  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In your select don't give names to each option

```
<select name="room" value="options">
<option value="Einstaklings">Alment Einstaklings Herbergi</option>
<option value="Tveggja">Alment Tveggja manna Herbergi</option>
<option value="Business">Business Herbergi</option>
<option value="Fjolskyldu">Fjölskyldu Herbergi</option>
<option value="Svitu">Svítu</option>
</SELECT>
```

2) You need to recieve your posted data, it will be in superglobal array $_POST

```
<?php 
   $room = $_POST['room'];
?>
```

3) You need to write this data to Data Base, after you made connection to it

Comment: Thanks allot :D It worked, you just fixed a problem that took me 2h to try to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I get it, but then again I don't read Icelandic (or whatever that is), but it looks like you are declaring a new array everytime in your function instead of using $room ?

Try replacing :

```
function generateSelect($name = '', $options = array()) {
```

with :

```
function generateSelect($name, $options) {
```